# PHP: Case-Insensitive Login Check

Tags: php, authentication, logic

As of right now I check if a user can login in this manner:

```
// simply logic:
if (username == usernameEntered && password == passwordEntered) {
```

My database has an entry of `Aaron` within my user's table. But if I try to login as `aaron` or `AARON` etc. It will deny me access. So it seems it is case sensitive. Is this a problem with my database or how I'm checking for login credentials?

I remember back when I fiddled with JavaScript, `/values/i` could be used for case insensitivity. Is there something like this for PHP checks?

Also, since I'm here, is there much difference between `isset();` and `empty();` when in reference to cookies/$_GET[]; requests?

Comment: You're not showing the code you're using to do the database query

Comment: What database system are you using? Can you show relevant code? If you're using MySQL, you don't have to worry about case-sensitivity, provided that the username is saved without adjustments (such as hashing).

Comment: Your code is very simplified, so this might be off - but it seems like you are actually storing the passwords plain-text, and not hashed?

Comment: As @Pekka said, it would be good to see the code for the query, in case there is another problem other than case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, use the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function. Just need to do something like this:

```
if(strtolower($username) == strtolower($usernameEntered))
```

As for **[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** and **[empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**, they are indeed different, but often they'll give you the same result. **isset()** tells you whether a variable was set at all (but it can still have no value). **empty()** tells in general whether the variable is equal to something. See the PHP documentation I linked to for each one. I would advise against using **empty()** for checking cookies and GET/POST values because empty strings and 0 are considered empty, which is probably not what you want. I would use isset() to see if the variable was set, and then further check it for whatever data you're looking for. Oftentimes you would want to deal with an empty string differently than no value at all.

Also, Pekka brought up in a comment that if you're finding the account in the database based on the username, then you really need to do the conversion to lowercase there. If so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(:username)
```

That's assuming you're using a prepared query with PDO. Otherwise just substitute your variable where I have `:username` (with proper string concatenation and so forth, of course. :)

**EDIT: As deceze brought up in the comments, using LOWER() in a query like this would be a really bad idea because it would have to convert every username in the table to lowercase for comparison and would render any index on the field useless. A much better way would be to store a lowercase version of the username in the database as well with an index on the field. When the user tries to log in, convert what they entered to lowercase and then do the comparison with that.**

Comment: Looks like TomS beat me to it on the strtolower answer. :)

Comment: No, `empty` is equivalent to `!isset || == false`. See http://kunststube.net/isset.

Comment: @Compeek, the more the better!

Comment: @deceze, that's merely the opposite condition of what I put. It just depends on whether he wants to do something if it's empty or do something if it's not empty. I wasn't saying my if statement was the same as `if empty`.

Comment: The point is, `empty` does *not* throw a warning, the `isset` check is already "built in". `isset && !empty` is redundant.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I wasn't sure when I posted it, but see that in the documentation now. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `WHERE LOWER(username)` is of course an extremely expensive solution, since it requires the database to lowercase *every username in the entire table every time this query is run* and forgoes the use of indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtolower()` or `strtoupper()` in both sides of the `if` condition.

```
if (strtolower(username) == strtolower(usernameEntered) && strtolower(password) == strtolower(passwordEntered))
```

These functions replace all upper letters with lower letters, or vice versa, allowing a case insensitive checking.

Also, you can see in detail the differences between `isset()` and `empty()` by checking the PHP documentation

[PHP: isset - Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

[PHP: empty - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: (I think using `strcasecmp` is equivalent:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php in case you prefer that) Edit: As @Compeek says below, probably better to use the strlower/strupper approach.

Comment: I would also keep passwords as case sensitive, it makes it harder to brute force.

Comment: @marnir The first comment on the documentation page for **strcasecmp** says this: _Don't forget this is a single-byte function: in Unicode strings it'll provide incoherent results as soon as both strings differ only in case. There doesn't seem to exist a built-in multi-byte alternative so you need to write your own, taking into account both character encoding and collation._ So I think you'd be safer using **strtolower** or **strtoupper**.

Comment: I don't think this is going to solve the problem, seeing as a database query is being made to fetch the account. *That* will need to be made case insensitive

Comment: @Pekka, in that case MySQL's **LOWER()** function would be used in pretty much the same way.

Comment: @Compeek  that is probably what an answer to the question should say... But the OP is being awfully unclear

Comment: I added it to my answer, but you're right, the question isn't clear as to where exactly the comparisons need to be done. But what you said would make the most sense and is the typical case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`COLLATE` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) in an SQL statement to choose the collation that is used for comparison when searching for the username in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` COLLATE utf8_general_ci = 'FoObAr'
```

Using a `_ci` (case insensitive) collation will let you find values regardless of their case. Make sure to choose the right collation though or you may get unexpected results, as other characters will be regarded as equal as well (e and é for example). You can also set the collation on the column directly, so you don't have to include `COLLATE` in every query.

What you really should do though is to **normalize** usernames before they go into the database, so you're always storing usernames in lowercase for example. Then, when searching the database, you also lowercase the term to be searched for before plugging it into the query. See [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower).

As for `isset` and `empty`: `isset` tells you whether a value exists at all, `empty` also tells you whether it's considered [empty](http://php.net/empty). Read the manual or http://kunststube.net/isset.

Comment: Regarding normalizing the username, sometimes you want to maintain the case for display purposes. You could always store the display version separately, but depending on the project, that might be overkill.

Comment: Fair point, but then I'd separate the idea of a "username used for login purposes" and a "display name". Let the display name be anything you like in Unicode and restrict the username to ASCII. Then again you might want to use the email address or OpenID/Oauth/BrowserID instead of a username then.

Comment: Indeed. I would probably separate them as well. I was thinking if the username was the exact same as the display name except for case, but even so it makes more sense to keep them separate, unless it's a really simple project where the extra validation to keep them identical wouldn't be worth the effort.