# Case Sensitive Login Issue - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When a user tries logging into their account, it doesn't work if they email has uppercase letters and the matching email in the database has lowercase. It's being case sensitive. Below is the code I'm using. Is anyone else having this issue?

```
$email       = Input::get('email');
$password    = Input::get('password');//edited for stackoverflow
$results     = User::where('email', '=', $email)->where('password', '=', $password)->get();
```

Comment: `strtolower(Input::get('email'));`

Comment: Yes, that is the default functionality. If you want it to not be case-insensitive, I would recommend using the strtolower() function when you register a new user, as well as before looking up a new user (in the relevant Register and Authenticate methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Case-Insensitive Login Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650210/php-case-insensitive-login-check)

Answer (score 2):

You just make it a lowercase check

`User::where('email', strtolower($email))`

And always store all emails as lower case in your database.

What concerns me is this this line:

`->where('password', '=', $password)`

I hope your not storing the passwords as plain text? You should be hashing them.

Comment: Thanks and if you look at the original question it has this comment //edited for stackoverflow, meaning I have a salt and hash on it.

Comment: The problem is the database has stored a ton of emails as upper and lower case. There is no way to get rid of the case sensitive part with Laravel
or PHP?

Comment: @SamJ. `UPDATE users SET email=LOWER(email)` should do the trick for that.

Answer (score 0):

You must use strtolower at the time of the registration and at the time of comparison

```
$email = strtolower(Input::get('email'));
$password = strtolower(Input::get('password'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined two answers to get the correct result.

First update all the emails to lowercase in the database:

```
UPDATE users SET email=LOWER(email)
```

Then make it so that when a user logs in, it makes it lower case:

```
User::where('email', strtolower($email))
```

Lastly make sure that you store the email as lowercase when any new users sign up.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Let us consider "registration" is the table in your database. Here is the code.


      public function login(Request $req)
          {
            $email = $req->input('email');
            $password = $req->input('password');

            $temail =  DB::table('registration')->select(DB::raw('email'))
            ->where(['email'=>$email])->get(); 
            //get the email field from database.
            $tpassword = DB::table('registration')->select(DB::raw('password'))
            ->where(['password'=>$password])->get();  
            //get the password field from database.
            $checkLogin = DB::table('registration')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
            settype($temail,"string");   //Convert the objects into strings
            settype($tpassword,"string");

            $vemail=strcmp($temail,$email);
            $vpwd=strcmp($tpassword,$password);

            if($username=="" or $password=="")
            {echo "enter the required fields....";
            }
            else if(count($checkLogin)>0){
            if(($email==-1 or $email==1) and ($vpwd==-1 or $vpwd==1)){
            {
                echo "Login successful.....\n";
            }
            else{
                echo "Login failed.... ";
            }}
    else
echo "Login failed...";
        }
```